# Updating a value within a nested object within Ember.js without using .get() .set()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following object structure and I need to get a specific title value and then set it to a new value. I know once you go within a nested object you lose the Ember object .get() and .set() methods. Trying to set the value the standard JavaScript way has led to an error saying must use ember.set().

This is what I want to happen when it observes a change to App.job.code but I get Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])

```
updateTitle: function(){
    App.jobs.jobProducts[0].allocations[0].allocationTitle = "test2";
}.observes("App.job.code")
```

How would this best be achieved? Thanks

```
App.jobs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    jobTitle: "This is the only job",
    jobProducts: [
      {
        id: 0,
        productTitle: "Product 1",
        allocations:[
          {
            id: 0,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 1",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 1"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 2",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 3"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 4"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        productTitle: "Product 2",
        allocations:[
          {
            id: 0,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 3",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 5"
              },
             {
               id: 1,
               deliveryTitle: "Delivery 6"
             }
           ]
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            allocationTitle: "Allocation 4",
            deliverys:[
              {
                id: 0,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 7"
              },
              {
                id: 1,
                deliveryTitle: "Delivery 8"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems accessing the object the standard vanilla way: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/74/edit

Try something like this, does it work for you:

```
console.log("Title before: "+App.jobs[0].jobProducts[0].allocations[0].deliverys[0].deliveryTitle);

App.jobs[0].jobProducts[0].allocations[0].deliverys[0].deliveryTitle = "FOO";

console.log("Title after: "+App.jobs[0].jobProducts[0].allocations[0].deliverys[0].deliveryTitle);
```

### Update:

After thinking about it, IMHO this is the best practice how something like your use case should be done, this way you can later use `.set()`, `.get()` and all other features the framework gives you:

Define your models with relationships

```
App.Job = DS.Model.extend({
  jobTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  jobProducts: DS.hasMany('App.JobProduct')
});

App.JobProduct = DS.Model.extend({
  productTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  allocations: DS.hasMany('App.Allocation')
});

App.Allocation = DS.Model.extend({
  allocationTitle: DS.attr('string'),
  deliveries: DS.hasMany('App.Delivery')
});

App.Delivery = DS.Model.extend({
  deliveryTitle: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And some FIXTURES to bring it to live:

```
App.Job.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    jobTitle: "This is the only job",
    jobProducts: [1,2]
  }
];

App.JobProduct.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productTitle: "Product 1",
    allocations:[1,2]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    productTitle: "Product 2",
    allocations:[3,4]
  }  
];

App.Allocation.FIXTURES = [/* shortened */];

App.Delivery.FIXTURES = [/* shortened */];
```

See here a full working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/78/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this it what I have been doing and it works when running this directly in the console but what I missed out before was that this runs in a function when it observes a change to another value. But it fails to update and errors saying 'Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])'

Comment: @scotta7exander, you have to options here, 1. you use vanilla javascript to access your non-ember object and loose ll the binding capabilities, or 2. you create/use ember objects to have bindings and all other features. question, do you use ember-data in your project?

Comment: @scotta7exander, updated my answer, have a look how something like your use case should be done "the ember way"

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, I agree this would be the best solution but for now I wanted to avoid using ember data. Your responses though gave me the idea of how I could do it though. I should model each nested section as an ember object and then for each record create instances of those objects. This means I should have access to .get() & .set() I have created a demo to show what I mean - [demo](http://jsbin.com/EhoROfu/6/edit)

Comment: @scotta7exander, nice translation! this is exactly how I would do it without ember-data.